# Create a bar chart with a different dimension for each bar - Tableau Public

Tags: charts, bar-chart, tableau-api

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
Country   | Dim1 | Dim2 | Dim3
Country A | 10   |  20  |  30
Country B | 20   |  40  |  10
```

I want to create a filtered bar chart, where each bar is a different dimension, and you can filter by country.

Thanks!

Comment: You might get better luck by reshaping your data:

Answer (score 1):

As Suggested above you can reshape your data.

Or

you can create a Bar chart with 3 bars. Drop the 3 dimensions to column or rows depending whether you want bar charts vertical or horizontal.

Then put the country filter in the filter pane and click show quick filter.
Now you should be able to filter the data based on the country all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an easier time if you reshape your data to have 3 fields (columns): Country, Dimension and Value.

Then you can place Country on the Filter shelf, Dimension on the Row shelf and Value on the Column shelf, assuming Value is a continuous measure.